# Lodash startsWith()

Tags: javascript, lodash, startswith

How is the last statement true? The string does not start with "b". Could someone explain the position of "1" and why it makes that statement true?

```js
var _ = require('lodash');
var result = _.startsWith('abc', 'b');

console.log(result);

result = _.startsWith('abc', 'b', 1);
console.log(result);
```

```
>node tester.js

false

true
```

Comment: The third argument is the position. See the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#startsWith)

Comment: You've set the position to search from (3 arg) to 1, and since `b` is the first item when starting from that position it returns `true`.

Comment: The first item `a` is at position `0`.  The second item `b` is at position `1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://lodash.com/docs/#startsWith) says the third parameter indicates the position to search from. So if you begin at index `1` then the string `abc` actually starts with `b` and thus it will return `true`.